# Scrape with python scrapy - I need return all values from the same tag

Tags: python, html, css, scrapy

I try scrape https://cryptorank.io/fundraising-platforms:
I need a blockchain information:
In scrapy shell I use the code:

```
fetch('https://cryptorank.io/fundraising-platforms')
**FIRST EDIT** they changed .bZTNAB to .iyBlmE
response.css('.iyBlmE').get()
```

And return:

```
'<td class="blockchain-icon__BlockchainIconWrapper-sc-1jbqlsx-1 bZTNAB"><a title="Solana" class="blockchain-icon__BlockchainIcon-sc-1jbqlsx-0 lktuZD"></a><a href="
/blockchains/solana"><img alt="Solana icon" class="styled__LinkIcon-sc-1dw6qb0-5 jpwBjO" src="https://img.api.cryptorank.io/coins/icon.solana1606979093056.png"></a
><a title="Ethereum" class="blockchain-icon__BlockchainIcon-sc-1jbqlsx-0 cvIVGk"></a><a href="/blockchains/ethereum"><img alt="Ethereum icon" class="styled__LinkIc
on-sc-1dw6qb0-5 jpwBjO" src="https://img.api.cryptorank.io/coins/icon.ethereum1524754015525.png"></a><a title="BNB" class="blockchain-icon__BlockchainIcon-sc-1jbql
sx-0 eJkzMZ"></a><a href="/blockchains/bnb"><img alt="BNB icon" class="styled__LinkIcon-sc-1dw6qb0-5 jpwBjO" src="https://img.api.cryptorank.io/coins/icon.binance%
20coin1645029040254.png"></a><a title="Polygon" class="blockchain-icon__BlockchainIcon-sc-1jbqlsx-0 dYSgum"></a><a href="/blockchains/matic-network"><img alt="Poly
gon icon" class="styled__LinkIcon-sc-1dw6qb0-5 jpwBjO" src="https://img.api.cryptorank.io/coins/icon.polygon1624610763534.png"></a><a title="Huobi Token" class="bl
ockchain-icon__BlockchainIcon-sc-1jbqlsx-0 cyYEun"></a><a href="/blockchains/huobi-token"><img alt="Huobi Token icon" class="styled__LinkIcon-sc-1dw6qb0-5 jpwBjO" 
src="https://img.api.cryptorank.io/coins/icon.huobi-token1524754545762.png"></a></td>'
```

But I need all name blockchain and this information is in this part `<a title="Polygon" class="blockchain-icon__BlockchainIcon-sc-1jbqlsx-0 dYSgum"></a>`, if I try:

```
response.css(".iyBlmE a::attr(title)").get()
```

Return only 'Solana' but I need all blockchains.

**EDIT** Add some images to explain better:
If I use `response.css(".iyBlmE a::attr(title)").getall()`  return a list with all itens of the column blockchain in.

[Image get .css using SelectorGadget extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIiSO.png)

[Image inspector the site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JyNH0.png)

[Run commands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hzuft.png)

Answer (score 0):

Only the Solana icon has the `bZTNAB` class. The rest all has different ones.

I'd go with the code snippet below.

`response.css('div[class^="blockchain-icon"] a::attr(title)).getall()`

Comment: Hi Róbert thanks for coment. I try it, but return an empty list. Well looks like they updated the site. The comand ```response.css(.iyBlmE').get()``` return that I want, but it's a dirty answer. I will edit the post to add some more images.